# wildcard SSL certificate generates error when no subdomain is used

Tags: iis, ssl, https

I have a webserver (IIS) with an SSL cert for *.mydomain.com

This works perfectly for https://anysubdomain.mydomain.com/ but going to https://mydomain.com/ causes a certificate mismatch error in IE (has not been tested in all other browsers).

Is there any way to work around this, or is it simply a problem with the way IE treats the wildcard in the certificate we have to live with?

Comment: There is no way to work around *and* IE is treating it correctly. See the [wildcard rules in RFC 2818](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2818#section-3.1) to understand why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way to remove the error message when accessing the site at https://mydomain.com is to put the base domain (mydomain.com) in as a Subject Alternative Name in the wildcard. Several certificate providers will add this for free (including DigiCert and Comodo) but you will need to reissue your certificate.