# Java Apache - POST and SSL

Tags: java, android, apache, post, ssl

I tried to make a **secure connection** between my **Android App** and the **PHP Server via SSL** and **Post**. However it's unfortunately not connecting to the Server, because the **SSL certificate can't be verified**.

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://example.me/api/index.php");
```

returns:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLExeption: hostname in certificate didn't match: <example.me> != <*.one.com> OR <*.one.com> or <one.com>
```

---

Is there a workaround for this problem, with which I can manualy verify it?
Because

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.me/api/index.php");
```

is working like a charm :/

---

**Full Code:**

```
public static String[] getList(String user, String pass, String addArray, String removeArray){
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://example.me/api/index.php");

            try {

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("addArray", addArray));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("removeArray", removeArray));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler(); 
                String ResponseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

                if(ResponseBody!=null){
                      String[] list = ResponseBody.split( Pattern.quote( ";" ) );
                      return list;
                 }else{
                      String[] error = {"empty"};
                      return error;
                 }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                String[] error = {e.toString()};
                return error;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                String[] error = {e.toString()};
                return error;
            }
}
```

Thanks for your help ;)

---

*(I replaced my DNS with example.me)*

Comment: If the certificate matched the domain name against which it was issued, there would not be a problem.  If you cant fix that (you should) see [How to handle invalid SSL certificates with Apache HttpClient?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828775/how-to-handle-invalid-ssl-certificates-with-apache-httpclient)

Comment: The certificate is tied to a specific domain name "xxx.com" specified when you created it. If you issue a request over https to anything other than "xxx.com"  - like "www.xxx.com" or "completelydifferent.com" you will get the error you are seeing.  (an exception is wildcard "*.xxx.com" certificates)  Open the url in a browser and you will see the same type of error.

Comment: @Alex K. Ok. My Chrome add-on sais that the certificate is from the type "*.example.me". So is it the exception you meant?

Comment: type `https://idontexist.example.me` into a browser, if it loads with no ssl error then you have a wildcard certificate,
type `https://example.me` into a browser if you get an ssl error then the root domain is not setup as a SAN, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445934/wildcard-ssl-certificate-generates-error-when-no-subdomain-is-used

Comment: @Alex K. Ok. I must admit that all the SSL stuff confuses me a lot. I found out that I have a "SNI" certificate.